# Css set delay on selected element in :hover

Tags: html, css, text, hover

I have a box and a 'something' button, whenever someone hovers over the 'onebysign' div the height of the element increases and some text appears, the problem is that the text appears immediately after you hover over the element, but when that happens it looks ugly since the text basically comes out of nowhere, same goes for when the user stops hovering over the element. I would like to have a delay in the text appearance just like what is happening with the div.

HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.events {
  padding: 20px 100px;
}

.textInfo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #085DAD;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.onebyone {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
}

.onebytext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
}

.onebysign {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: height 1s;
}

.onebytext,
.onebysign {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.onebysign:hover {
  height: 300px;
}

.onebyform {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.submitBtn {
  background-color: #0099CC;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.onebysign:before {
  content: "";
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, white 47%, transparent 50%);
  left: 0;
  top: -30px;
}

.signText {
  display: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.onebysign:hover .signText {
  transition-delay: 1s;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row events">
  <div class="onebyone">
    <div class="onebytext">
      <div class="textInfo">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="onebysign">
      <span class="signText">This is a sample text. It looks pretty good now, but the longer you make the text, the more ugly it looks...</span>
      <form class="onebyform" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
        <button class="submitBtn">Something</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've tried a `transition-delay` on the `signText` element, and that's a start in the right direction.

Instead of transitioning the `display` property, we'll transition the `opacity` property. Like this:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.events {
  padding: 20px 100px;
}

.textInfo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #085DAD;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.onebyone {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
}

.onebytext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
}

.onebysign {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.onebytext,
.onebysign {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.onebysign:hover {
  height: 300px;
  color: #000000;
}

.onebyform {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.submitBtn {
  background-color: #0099CC;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.onebysign:before {
  content: "";
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, white 47%, transparent 50%);
  left: 0;
  top: -30px;
}

.signText {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 400px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
}

.onebysign:hover .signText {
  transition-delay: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row events">
  <div class="onebyone">
    <div class="onebytext">
      <div class="textInfo">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="onebysign">
      <span class="signText">This is a sample text. It looks pretty good now, but the longer you make the text, the more ugly it looks...</span>
      <form class="onebyform" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
        <button class="submitBtn">Something</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The main takeaway is to make sure the property being transitioned is an [animatable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). `opacity` is, `display` is not.

Answer (score 2):

There are any number of things you can do with this. Here's one example.

```
.onebysign {
  ...
  overflow: hidden;
}

.signText {
  opacity: 0;
  ...
}

.onebysign:hover .signText {
  ...
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/4za9mjzs/2)